# How can I set viewport size of Safari?

Tags: safari, safari-extension

Is there any extension that allows to setup viewport size of Safary. Something like web developer for Mozilla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" >
```